# Despite layout change (without geometry package) `multicols` still use former textwidth

Tags: multicol, geometry, layout, textwidth

For testing purposes, I'm trying to reproduce my geometry/layout without using `geometry` package (It is only loaded to use the `showframe` option).

So far, it works fine. But in my main document I use a command to produce a fully automated twocolumn section with the `multicol` package. If I now replace the `\newgeometry` command, which works perfectly fine in the main document, with my adapted layout dimensions, the layout itself changes, **but** the columns still are typesetted using the former `textwidth` of my initial layout dimensions, as indicated by `showframe`.

Here's my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,english,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{-5.4mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{34.6mm}
\setlength\topmargin{-23.4mm}
\setlength\headheight{4.2mm}
\setlength\headsep{8.8mm}
\setlength\marginparsep{4.5mm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{40.5mm}
\setlength\footskip{10.5mm}
\setlength\marginparpush{1.8mm}
\setlength\voffset{0mm}
\setlength\hoffset{0mm}
\setlength\textwidth{130mm}
\setlength\textheight{262mm}

\NewDocumentCommand{\columnpart}{+m}{
    \newpage
    \begingroup
    \setlength\oddsidemargin{-5.4mm}
    \setlength\evensidemargin{12.1mm}
    \setlength\topmargin{-23.4mm}
    \setlength\headheight{4.2mm}
    \setlength\headsep{8.8mm}
    \setlength\marginparsep{4.5mm}
    \setlength\marginparwidth{18mm}
    \setlength\footskip{10.5mm}
    \setlength\marginparpush{1.8mm}
    \setlength\voffset{0mm}
    \setlength\hoffset{0mm}
    \setlength\textwidth{152.5mm}
    \setlength\textheight{262mm}
    \setlength\columnsep{1cm}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
    #1
\end{multicols*}
    \endgroup
    \newpage
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\columnpart{\blindtext[5]}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

What do I have to change, to make `multicols` adapt the new `textwidth` set inside the command without using additional packages?

Comment: well look into the geometry code and check what it is doing.

Comment: Its a whole lot of code, but I think i got it. Overlooked it the first time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I may have overlooked something in the `geometry` package. Just inserted the following lines taken from the `geometry` package (`\Gm@changelayout` definition) at the end of the code inside the newcommand:

```latex
    \setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
    \setlength\columnsep{5mm}%
    \if@twocolumn%
    \advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
    \divide\columnwidth\tw@%
    \@firstcolumntrue%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}%
```

Now it works. Sorry for wasting anybodys time due to my lack of thoroughness ;)

Comment: you are missing `%` on the first two lines and have unneeded `%` on the next 4

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the hint, added the missing 2. But the last 7 lines are more or less copied from `geometry`, thus, I just left the `%` untouched. Only line there without `%` is `\advance\columnwidth-\columnsep`.

Comment: well they don't harm, they just do nothing, but keeping same as your original source helps highlight the differences so yes keep them:-)